# android: ListView with Checkbox: row should not be focused

Tags: android, layout

I have a ListView with rows containing one CheckBox, some Images, TextViews and so on. If I select a row only the checkbox should activate. No focus of the row, no highlight of the CheckBox. 
Currently when I select a row the background becomes blue (holo light color). Thats what I do not want. I want no colors, only the CheckBox activated/deactivated.

How can I do this?

My Layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingTop="2dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/test"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <my.custom.ProgressChart
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_width="181px"
                    android:layout_height="31px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:text="@string/test"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're after. Could you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: you are trying to make a list in which rows are selected only if the checkbox is activated. You do not want any focusing of rows and checkbox until checkbox is selected? am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the selector, set the `android:listSelector` attribute on your `ListView`.

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Check/uncheck the `CheckBox` when the row is selected in the `OnItemClickListener`.

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }

});
```